# Making Google Plus login button invisible after login

Tags: android

How can I make the Google Plus login button invisible after login?

I have implemented as mentioned in [Getting Started with the Google+ Platform for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Set The button visibility attribute to "gone" after the login is completed.